Sending approval in Power App with attachment
I would like to generate a pdf from Power App Gallery, send it out by email, and get approval by team. I can do the first part successfully, however I cannot send out the approval with attachment. I tried to change the file to JSON and word, however it is still showing errors without any explanation. It would be much appreciated if anyone could help.
The code:
Set(
    PDFContent,
    {
        contentBytes: JSON(
            PDF(
                ResultMainContainer_Test,
                {
                    Orientation: PaperOrientation.Portrait,
                    Size: PaperSize.A4,
                    DPI: 150,
                    ExpandContainers: true
                }
            ),
            JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData
        ),
        name: "Management Review - Executive Summary - " & GalleryEntityLabel_Test.Text & ".pdf"
    }
);

Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
    ApproverDropDownList_Test.Selected.'Manager email',
    "Approval Request: Management Review- " & GalleryEntityLabel_Test.Text,
    "Please review and approve Management Review  - " & GalleryEntityLabel_Test.Text & " by " & Text(TargetDate, "[$-en-US]mm/dd/yyyy") & ".",
    {
        From: User().Email,
        Cc: "quincy@gmail.com", 
        Attachments: Table(
            {
                ContentBytes: PDF(ResultMainContainer_Test,
                    {
                        Orientation: PaperOrientation.Portrait,
                        Size: PaperSize.A4,
                        DPI: 150,
                        ExpandContainers: true 
                    }
                ),
                Name: "Management Review - Executive Summary - " & GalleryEntityLabel_Test.Text & ".pdf"
            }
        )
    }
);

ApprovalEmail.Run(ApproverDropDownList_Test.Selected.'Manager email',Today(),{file:PDFContent})

Power Automate setting


